# Applications keep showing up twice on the launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

I just did a fresh install of 11.10 Desktop 64-bit. When trying to add some new application to the launcher weird things are happening.

The problem in the following:
I tried opening a Terminal from the Dash. When the terminal icon appeared in the Launcher, I chose Keep in Launcher. Then I close the terminal. As expected the Terminal icon is still in the Launcher. So far so good.
Now, if I open a Terminal using the Launcher, a *second* Terminal icon appears, and stays after closing. If I open Terminal again, a *third* will appear and so on.

Screenshot:

[image]

The same happens with other applications that were not initially in the Launcher, but not with the original ones, like Ubuntu One.

**Update:**
The problem can be solved by logging out and in again every time I add a new icon to the launcher. It's definitely a bug. I shall report it.

**Update 2:**
[Bug reported](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/940763)

Comment: I experienced this problem on a 32-bit system (i386), too. Does it appear after a reboot (or after a session restart)?

Comment: Yeah, I've got this problem as well sometimes (about once a month and only with Firefox for now). Seems to be something Ubuntu borrowed from Windows 7, where I first experienced this issue (at school) :p I'd report it as a bug if I were you, because then there's a good chance it will get fixed before Ubuntu 12.04 gets released.

Comment: I could successfully keep a program in the launcher after logging out and in again. However, in the new session the problem persists if I add new programs to the launcher. So I need to log out every time I keep a program in the launcher.

Comment: If you temporarily move all the files from ~/.local/share/applications to another folder (e.g.~/backup) logout and login, does the problem reoccur?

Comment: @fossfreedom No, it does not help. There was a single file in ~/.local/share/applications: mimeapps.list.

Comment: ... is this user specific? create a new user account and see if they have the same issue.

Comment: @fossfreedom No, it's not user specific. I created new users, both Standard and Administrator. The problem persists.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [How to report a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). Regards,